# File is not sent via ftp - error: "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: bash, ftp

This is the bash code:

```
ftp -n <ftpadress> <<EOT
<credentials> 
binary
put $pathfile$reportfile $remotepath$reportfile
put $pathfile$logfile $remotepathlog$logfile
quit
EOT
```

This is the output:

```
a <files_to_add> 
put <files_to_add_with_path> <files_to_add_with_remote_path> 
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I checked the arguments of the put command and they are correct. Finally I check in the FTP and  is not there

I have two questions:

1. Why is not transferred?
2. What does the "The parameter is incorrect" mean?

**IMPORTANT NOTE: The file to be uploaded to the FTP contained the colon in the file name**

Comment: Does any of the involved filesystems not like `:` in filenames maybe?  Are you transferring the files to a Windows system?

Comment: The history is no longer visible. There's o longer any need to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kusalanada suggested, Windows did not like the symbol ":"

I changed the name of the file, from

```
file_2019-06-11_14:54:37.tar
```

to

```
file_02019-06-11_145437.tar
```